# Why is setting the y position of an object as the height of UIScreen divided by 2 not placing it at the top of the screen?

Tags: swift

I am currently creating a rhythm game and want to place a "beat" object (a circular object) at the top of the screen when the game starts. This object is an SKShapeNode, and to set its y position, I used `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2` (divided by 2 since the origin is in the middle of the screen). However, this results in the object placed around halfway from the edge of the screen to the middle of the screen [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne8em.png).

In the class I declare:

```
let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
var screenWidth: CGFloat!
var screenHeight: CGFloat!
```

Then later initialize screenWidth and screenHeight like so:

```
screenWidth = screenRect.size.width
screenHeight = screenRect.size.height
```

Finally, the position is set as:

```
self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: screenHeight / 2)
```

In the initializer

Why is the object not at the top of the screen and how would I fix it?

Comment: Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: @DanielStorm Could you explain...? And how to fix it, please. Sorry, I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my problem. I just needed to add the line `scene.size = view.bounds.size` to my GameViewController. This made the scene size fit the screen size, therefore, correcting the values.